# passing bearer Authorization header to AWS function using curl

Tags: curl, aws-lambda

I am trying to query a lambda endpoint from the command line, but having issues using a curl request to send a string authorization token. What am I doing wrong here?

**Attempt 1**

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer this is my secret string token' https://myurl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/beta/lambdaip
```

> {"message":"'this' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'Bearer this is my secret string token'."}

**Attempt 2**

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authentication:Bearer this is my secret string token' https://myurl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/beta/lambdaip
```

> {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}

**Attempt3**

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer=Token this is my secret string token' https://myurl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/beta/lambdaip
```

> {"message":"Authorization header must begin with the algorithm name, which cannot include an equal-sign: 'Bearer=Token this is my secret string token'"}

Comment: Did you figure it out at the end? I'm also running into this and the answer given here is not clear to me :(

Answer (score 0):

For a similar scenario, I had to trigger AWS API Gateway stage deploy: `beta` is the one it should apply as per example request.

Also, I had very similar code as *Attempt 1* for requests.